"Prefer named exports import/no-default-export" in the React JS Redux Toolkit project
When I do yarn build, then I am getting an error in the React JS Redux-Toolkit project:

Prefer named exports import/no-default-export

At this line of code:
export default orders.reducer;

Due to the error mentioned, I am not able to run the yarn build command.
Orders slice:
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { ORDER_SLICE } from 'constants/Constants';
import { envConfig } from 'envConfig';
import { httpClient } from 'httpClient';
import { GetOrdersType, OrdersType } from 'redux/interface/Orders';

const initialState: OrdersType = {
  data: null,
  totalCount: null,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

const orders = createSlice({
  name: ORDER_SLICE.NAME,
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getOrdersData.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(getOrdersData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.data = action.payload.orders;
      state.totalCount = Number(action.payload.pageable.totalCount);
    });
    builder.addCase(getOrdersData.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    });
  },
});

export default orders.reducer;

export const getOrdersData = createAsyncThunk(
  ORDER_SLICE.GET_ORDERS_DATA,
  async (config:GetOrdersType, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await httpClient?.get(`${envConfig.apiOrders}?size=${config.size}&page=${config.currentPage}`);
      return response?.data;
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log('error ', error);
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  },
);


You have a few options:

Change your linting rules to allow default exports

Disable the lint rule for that specific line
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-default-export
export default orders.reducer;


Use a named export like your project seems to be setup for
export const { reducer } = orders;

import { reducer as ordersReducer } from '../path/to/orders.slice';




Thanks. It's working after your suggestion.
